# Is CPU mining worthwhile for Litecoin? FPGA? GPU?

Tags: litecoin, solo-mining, mining-profitability, cpu-mining

I'm interested in solo mining on Litecoin.  Where can I learn about (or what math is required) two tell if this is feasible/profitable?
Currently I have 30+ CPUs running as solo miners for 40 hours and so far nothing has turned up.  Are there any optimizations I should do to the miner?

Answer (score 2):

Litecoin CPU ScryptMiner

Download

http://www.mediafire.com/?l8i99fbyn41n97a

I have an i7 getting 40 k/Hash which is not too bad

Considering that with cgminer config correctly you will get an k/Hash result similar to the M/Hash result for your GPU mining activities

Check this out for an complete guide of what your outputs should be using both reaper & cgminer

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=117221.0

I think that given i5 cpu and lots as in 30 that u have @ your disposal then LTC should be a goer

mrb stated that with correctly configered s/w LTC & BTC mining should be on a par of ~ 0.0041/0.0040 BTC/LTC per hour for (600 m-Hash BTC/600 k-hash LTC) GPU card setup

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=131809.msg1414530#msg1414530

Comment: Do you have a better link for the download...?

Comment: You are not answering the question

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend solo mining with CPU only, it would take a really long time to find a block. If you don't like pool mining, you can download the pool software and run your own private pool where you will connect all your CPUs.

If it is profitable depends on your expenses. Generally speaking using CPU to mine BTC/LTC if you have to pay the electricity is not profitable any longer. But if you don't pay the electricity (for example is included in server hosting costs) and already have the CPUs/servers available, then your expenses are zero. So even if you would earn one cent per month it would be profitable :)

I am using pooler's cpuminer on few servers - https://github.com/pooler/cpuminer